# GCP egress from push notification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I notice that there are some network egress from my GCP server.
I'm using Firebase push notification service, is it the reason for the egress network flow?

[egress1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uTXt.png)

[egress2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s24Tg.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question and let us know about the architecture of your project. How you are integrating your VM instance server with firebase push notification. There's not much more we can say without you detailing the question and explaining the background for us. Please see how you can ask a good question in stackoverflow following these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I using firebase push notification and Node.js server to push some message when user receive message from others.

Comment: I see the second image you have attached has a resource type “ VM instance”. Can you explain the significance of the VM instance in this process of integration of Firebase with Node js  Backend to enable push notifications?